# How to connect to Amazon Web Service RDS on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I've set up a DB Instance on AWS, and looking around all the guides I should now be able to go on MySQL Workbench and connect it succesfully, as I have a hostname, port, user ID and password.

However, when I enter all the details I specified when creating the instance, I get the error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at  with user

then below it says the same error with (10060) in brackets.  I looked up this error but couldn't find any relevant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two common causes of connection failures to a new DB instance are:

1. The DB instance was created using a security group that does not authorize connections from the device or Amazon EC2 instance where the MySQL application or utility is running. If the DB instance was created in a VPC, it must have a VPC security group that authorizes the connections. If the DB instance was created outside of a VPC, it must have a DB security group that authorizes the connections.
2. The DB instance was created using the default port of 3306, and your company has firewall rules blocking connections to that port from devices in your company network. To fix this failure, recreate the instance with a different port.

You can use SSL encryption on connections to an Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance. For information, see Using SSL with a MySQL DB Instance.

I recommend to go through below document, it will help to fix your issue.

[Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

Comment: I took a look through all the settings of my instance and saw that the setting "Publicly Accessible" was set to Yes, but the Security Group was "default (sg-cc3271a9)(active)", with a description of "default VPC security group". Could this be the issue, and how would I resolve it?

Comment: You need create a new security group and allow default port number (3306) opened and assign it to the RDS DB to open to public (0.0.0.0/0) or nominated IP address/range.

Comment: ahh thank you!!! it's all working now, I can connect on MySQL workbench. Really appreciate it, I don't know what I'd do without this website.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 10060 indicates connectivity problem, look into these settings / configuration -

1. Check the port configured for listening - 3306 ( or some other port )
2. Security Group is opened for the above identified port for your IP ( make it 0.0.0.0/0 as acid test )
3. If the RDS is inside VPC, you need route table entry with Internet gateway